# Python - Plot series from array if above a threshold

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

First question and fairly novice python user here.

I'm using matplotlib to produce line plots of data series from a numpy array. The arrays are 170 x 481, where there are 169 series of 480 data points each (1st column are my x-axis values, top row is a header with column names).

In my data, all of the values range between 0. and 1. However, many of these series have data values approximating to 0. and so I'd like to only plot series that have a peak value in the series above a certain threshold.

A simplified example array would be the following:

```
myarray = [['thickness' 'a' 'b' 'c']
 ['0.25' '0.5' '0.2' '0.001']
 ['0.5' '0.4' '0.3' '0.002']
 ['0.75' '0.3' '0.2' '0.001']]
```

Manually plotting with matplotlib:

```
plt.plot(myarray[1:,0], myarray[1:,1], label='a')
plt.plot(myarray[1:,0], myarray[1:,2], label='b')
plt.plot(myarray[1:,0], myarray[1:,3], label='c')
plt.xlabel('Thickness')
plt.ylabel('Intensity')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
```

Result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKjoS.png).

In this case I'm interested in plotting `a` and `b`, but not `c`. Whilst it is easy to manually exclude here, this is not so easy with 169 series.

The route I've been trying is to use a `for` loop with `numpy.amax()` to only plot slices/series above a threshold:

```
for i in myarray[:,1:]:
    if np.amax(myarray[1:,i]) > 0.015: #example threshold
        plt.plot(myarray[1:,0], myarray[1:,i])
```

Using this route unfortunately doesn't work, as it throws up an IndexError as the indices in the array are floats, not int or bool:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-d5338b9231af> in <module>()
      1 for i in myarray[:,1:]:
----> 2     if np.amax(myarray[1:,i]) > 0.015:
      3         plt.plot(myarray[1:,0], myarray[1:,i])

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

My question specifically is how would you go about selecting and plotting a series of data that possesses an element above a desired threshold (without modifying the data in the array)?

EDIT: Following @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 's answer, it requires the whole array to be floats (it turns out by inserting the header strings into my array at an earlier time I had inadvertently turned the float data to strings). In this case you get a TypeError, so keep this in mind if anyone encounters that.

Comment: You will always help yourself if producing a [mcve] of the issue. I.e. you create some sample data with the same structure as your data but some 4x4 matrix might be enough here. Then posting this example with the sample data allows to easily reproduce the issue by copy paste from the question and you may usually have an answer within minutes.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a brief example for some context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to loop over the indizes of your array along the columns.

```
for i in range(1, myarray.shape[1]):
    if np.amax(myarray[1:,i]) > 0.015: 
        plt.plot(myarray[1:,0], myarray[1:,i])
```

Comment: I initially had an issue with a TypeError with this method, but that was due to an error with my array being in strings, not floats. This worked well once I'd resolved that, thanks.